# I am born from the combination of a forest and ore and used to cover the world in darkness, what am I?

Tags: riddle

I am born from the combination of a forest and ore and used to cover the world in darkness, what am I?

Hint: It is not in the sky and it is not coal.

Comment: My friend, on this site there's a custom that you don't name the puzzle with the same text that is the puzzle. This creates unnecessary repetitions. You probably ought to rename it.

Answer (score 7):

Is it

> The earth itself?

Combination of forest and ore:

> That seems like a fairly good poetical definition of the earth.

Used to cover the world in darkness:

> There is always one-half of the earth in darkness, due to the earth itself blocking the sun's light, and that darkness traverses the entire globe  every 24 hrs (barring the North and South Poles in summer and winter.)

Comment: I am not so satisfied with the darkness part :D

Comment: OK I'll try again!

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> War

Reason

> Fire is used to burn and to smelt ore to build weapons

Comment: Ummmm...I think you mixed up your reasoning and your answer - looks like you changed one without changing the other.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> A cave

I am born from the combination of a forest and ore

> A cave may be formed in a forest and is a source of all kinds of ores.

and used to cover the world in darkness

> Inside a cave is very dark without any light.

---

Or, are you

> Global warming

I am born from the combination of a forest and ore

> Pollution released from forest materials and ores like carbon may cause the global warming.

and used to cover the world in darkness

> It could eventually end up putting the whole world in a serious danger.

---

(Both are not in the sky and not coal itself.)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Lead

Because

> Lead is very dark and it is used to shield equipment and people from radiation so it essentially blocks you or the equipment from the world

It could also be

> Nuclear bomb

Since

> Uranium ore is refined using natural materials and nuclear bombs would obviously cover the world in darkness

Answer (score 3):

What about

> Asphalt

Because

> Tar is made from organic material - and is used to bind ore together to make roads, also known as blacktop - thus covering the world in darkness

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> haze

Explanation:

> It is made of clouds filled with sand created from the forest and when it is found the world darkens

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Walkerbo's answer, could it be

> A GUN?

This is because

> Guns (historically, eg. flintlock pistols, and rifles) are built using wood and metal; wood is the product of a forest and metal is the product of ore; so guns would be the combination of the two. They cover the world in darkness because they are continually used for killing others.

Answer (score 1):

My Answer

> Smoke

Because

> Ores, such as coal, burn, and as does wood. The fire creates smoke, that if there is enough of, will cover the skies, and thus the world, with darkness.